Cover-Art Finder icons for EPUB stops working after MacOS 15.1 upgrate
I have a large collection of EPUB ebook files. Up until now, the Finder has always displayed cover art from the EPUB file as the file icon.
But after the 15.1 upgrade, I now find that all my EPUB files use the generic iBooks file icon.
Does anyone know how to revert this behavior?

Have you tried restarting since the update? Even though the update process usually includes a couple of restarts, I've found there are sometimes lingering issues like this that will resolve themselves after one more.

I can confirm that all my epubs (from various sources) display with generic icon. I suspect we have been caught by the Sequoia changes to QuickLook and icon generation. macOS no longer supports old QuickLook generators. I am yet to explore solutions, but for background see https://eclecticlight.co/2024/10/31/how-sequoia-has-changed-quicklook-and-its-thumbnails/ and https://eclecticlight.co/2024/11/04/how-does-quicklook-create-thumbnails-and-previews-with-an-update-to-mints/

@BillHorvath I hang my head in shame. Reboot and all but a few EPUBs now have preview and icon.

@Gilby Excellent! I'm glad that helped.

Just following up on this... Yes, after restarting, the preview icons were all restored! Thanks :)
